# Log analytics user-defined function returning 'Body of the callable expression cannot be empty'

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When defining and executing a saved function in Log Analytics as follows, I can see results:

```
let cfd = () {
    let TimeSpanGranularity = 5m;
    let MinimumEventsInTimeSpan = 500;
    let ErrorRatioThreshold = 0.9;
    let TimeSpanTraces = allTraces
    | where timestamp > ago(TimeSpanGranularity)
    | parse message with * ") " EventText
    | parse EventText with EventName ":" *
    | extend Event=coalesce(EventName,EventText,message)
    | where severityLevel >= 1;
    let ShouldFireData = TimeSpanTraces
    | summarize ErrorOrAboveCount=todecimal(sumif(itemCount, severityLevel>=3)), TotalEventCount=todecimal(sum(itemCount))
    | extend ErrorRatioThreshold
    | extend ErrorRatio=100.0*ErrorOrAboveCount/TotalEventCount
    | project FireAlert = ErrorRatio>=ErrorRatioThreshold and TotalEventCount>=MinimumEventsInTimeSpan;
    let ShouldFire = toscalar(ShouldFireData);
    TimeSpanTraces
    | where ShouldFire == true and severityLevel >=3;
};
cfd();
```

However, after saving the function, and attempting to invoke the saved function as follows:

```
cfd()
```

I am seeing the following error:

"Body of the callable expression cannot be empty"

I have spent way too much time trying to get this to work.. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that you are not using Kusto directly (not using Azure Data Explorer), and utilizing Application Insights to "save function".
I propose to change the tags to reflect this - and get this addressed by Application Insights team

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the function was saved as:

```
let cfd = () {
    let TimeSpanGranularity = 5m;
    let MinimumEventsInTimeSpan = 500;
    let ErrorRatioThreshold = 0.9;
    let TimeSpanTraces = allTraces
    | where timestamp > ago(TimeSpanGranularity)
    | parse message with * ") " EventText
    | parse EventText with EventName ":" *
    | extend Event=coalesce(EventName,EventText,message)
    | where severityLevel >= 1;
    let ShouldFireData = TimeSpanTraces
    | summarize ErrorOrAboveCount=todecimal(sumif(itemCount, severityLevel>=3)), TotalEventCount=todecimal(sum(itemCount))
    | extend ErrorRatioThreshold
    | extend ErrorRatio=100.0*ErrorOrAboveCount/TotalEventCount
    | project FireAlert = ErrorRatio>=ErrorRatioThreshold and TotalEventCount>=MinimumEventsInTimeSpan;
    let ShouldFire = toscalar(ShouldFireData);
    TimeSpanTraces
    | where ShouldFire == true and severityLevel >=3;
};
```

and not

```
let cfd = () {
    ...
};
cfd();
```

It may happen if this specific section of the query and not the whole query is highlighted in the UI.

Could you please try again?
Please note in this case the saved function body can simply be:

```
let TimeSpanGranularity = 5m;
let MinimumEventsInTimeSpan = 500;
let ErrorRatioThreshold = 0.9;
let TimeSpanTraces = allTraces
| where timestamp > ago(TimeSpanGranularity)
| parse message with * ") " EventText
| parse EventText with EventName ":" *
| extend Event=coalesce(EventName,EventText,message)
| where severityLevel >= 1;
let ShouldFireData = TimeSpanTraces
| summarize ErrorOrAboveCount=todecimal(sumif(itemCount, severityLevel>=3)), TotalEventCount=todecimal(sum(itemCount))
| extend ErrorRatioThreshold
| extend ErrorRatio=100.0*ErrorOrAboveCount/TotalEventCount
| project FireAlert = ErrorRatio>=ErrorRatioThreshold and TotalEventCount>=MinimumEventsInTimeSpan;
let ShouldFire = toscalar(ShouldFireData);
TimeSpanTraces
| where ShouldFire == true and severityLevel >=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this. Also if you want to add a parameter, you should provide an actual input. This was counter-intuitive to me as function definitions usually don't require literals.

```
// Query that appends a question mark to a provided name parameter
let nameWithQuestionMark = (name:string) {
  print strcat(name, " is it you?")
};
let name = "John";
nameWithQuestionMark(name)
```

Then save the query with a parameter:

[image: save]

After you call in a workbook like so:

```
nameWithQuestionMark('databach');
```